# how to understand the "ch=ch1" in the following codes?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I cannot understand the meaning of "ch=ch1" and why does it can print the prime number? does someone can explain it for me? I am learning the Go.

```
    // Copyright 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
    // Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
    // license that can be found in the LICENSE file.package main
    package main

    import "fmt"

    // Send the sequence 2, 3, 4, ... to channel 'ch'.
    func generate(ch chan int) {
        for i := 2; ; i++ {
            ch <- i // Send 'i' to channel 'ch'.
        }
    }

    // Copy the values from channel 'in' to channel 'out',
    // removing those divisible by 'prime'.
    func filter(in, out chan int, prime int) {
    for {
        i := <-in // Receive value of new variable 'i' from 'in'.
        if i%prime != 0 {
            out <- i // Send 'i' to channel 'out'.
        }
    }
}

// The prime sieve: Daisy-chain filter processes together.
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int) // Create a new channel.
    go generate(ch)      // Start generate() as a goroutine.
    for {
        prime := <-ch
        fmt.Print(prime, " ")
        ch1 := make(chan int)
        go filter(ch, ch1, prime)
        ch = ch1
    }
}
```

could someoen explain these code for me? I have been learnt the Go for serveral days.

Answer (score 0):

`ch` is the "current channel". The loop is the following:

1. You starting with the channel filled by generate. It's the channel of all integers. First number from this channel is 2 (prime number).
2. Then you create `ch1` which is the channel of all integers without numbers divisible by 2.
3. `=` is the assignment operator. By using `ch = ch1` you're telling that current channel is the channel of all integers without divisible by 2.
4. New loop iteration. First number from current channel is 3. You creating `ch1` as current channel without numbers divisible by 3.
5. Assign `ch1` to be current channel. So now current channel is channel of all numbers without divisible by 2 without divisible by 3.
6. Repeat

Comment: when runing the ch=ch1, does it will change the data in generator function?  what if the ch=ch1 is finished before the fliter function? since we cannot garantee the order of goroutines and the code in main process.

Comment: Both `generate` and `filter` run forever, along with the channels they are attached to. You just add more filters with more channels and just print the first number to reach the end of the pipeline. Altering what `ch` points to has no effect on the go-process running `filter` - the setup of that was completed on the previous line. Try working through it with paper and pencil.